# Magento: Product attribute as a sticker

Tags: css, magento, magento-1.7, product

I created a custom attribute with 10 options ( mix10, mix20 .... mix100). What I am trying to do is when I select mix10, to get "mix10" as a custom sticker on product thumbnail image. I have no clue how to add this custom attribute as a small CSS on the thumbnail image of products.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your going to have to look at z-index the styling property and then you're going to need to get the attribute in relation to the image.

Create a simple div over your product image

```
<div id="mix-sticker" class="mix-sticker_<?php echo $_product->getAttributecode()?>">
<img YOUR PRODUCT IMAGE/>
</div>
```

Then for your CSS styling you'd need to do something similar to

```
#mix-sticker {
z-index:500;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
}

.mix-sticker_1 {
background:url(../images/mix1.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Hi Florin, this was basic example of how to achieve the product label.

For sale and new labels example
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/31385/P0/

But rather than calling the sale date or new date, you should call your attribute instead

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want to put this sticker on the thumbnails in your category listing. Open up `/app/design/frontend/[YOURPACKAGE]/[YOURTHEME]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` and find the section that outputs your thumbnail images. It will likely look something like:

```
<li>
  <a>
    <img />
  <a>
  ...
</li>
```

What you will need to do is insert some code right inside the `<a>` link:

```
             <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
            <div class="sticker">             
                <?php if($_product->getData('mix')=='mix10'){echo '<span class="mix10">'.$this->__('Mix10').'</span>';  }
                  elseif($_product->getData('mix')=='mix20'){echo '<span class="mix20">'.$this->__('Mix20').'</span>';  }
                  elseif ...
                ?>
            </div>
```

Added all your options as `elseif` statements.

Then, in your CSS file, add styling for those stickers. That file will likely be located at `/skin/frontend/[YOURPACKAGE]/[YOURTHEME]/css/styles.css`:

```
.sticker {
    position: absolute; 
    left: -5px; 
    top: -5px;

}
.sticker > span {
    font-size: 0;
    text-indent: -77777px;
    width: 75px; /*image size*/
    height: 75px; /*image size*/
    background: url(../images/mix10.png) no-repeat left top; /*image location*/
    display: block;
}
.sticker > span.mix20 {background: url(../images/mix20.png) no-repeat left top; margin: 1px 0 0 1px}
...
```

Add styles for all the sticker options you used in your PHTML file and then make sure your images are loaded to the server.

Comment: Was this answer able to help you?